# How to passthrougha PCI Express (PCIe) USB 3.0 Card to a virtual machine?

Tags: drivers, usb, kernel, kvm-virtualization, xhci-hcd

I am trying to Pass through a PCI Express (PCIe) USB 3.0 card to a virtual machine. However, XHCI_HCD is compiled into the kernel and thus grabbing the device before VFIO.

If I unbind the device from XHCI_HCD the device does not work in Windows.

I have tried compiling a custom Kernel using Ubuntu's config only changing xhci to module, however, that crashes on startup.

Please advise on how to get physical USB hardware device through to virtual windows machine. Note, I have tried with XEN which worked fine, but then the NVIDIA GPU has "code 43" which I was unable to resolve.

Answer (score 0):

usually libvirt will do the detaching right when you start the guest due to the `managed` attribute used in the [hostdev](https://libvirt.org/formatdomain.html#elementsHostDevSubsys) definition.
But if you want/need to debug this detach-from-host phase you can identify the libvirt name of your device via

```
  $ virsh nodedev-list --tree
```

Once you know that you can detach it from the host and bind it to vfio to be ready for passthrough, here an example:

```
$ virsh nodedev-detach pci_0005_01_00_0 --driver vfio
```

You still have to follow the other constraints of enabling IOMMU/DMAR correctly and to have the to-be-passed device in its own IOMMU group (or pass all devices of the group).

You can add the [hostdev](https://libvirt.org/formatdomain.html#elementsHostDevSubsys) to the guest definition and if you are unsure what to add there you can use `virsh nodedev-dumpxml` to get the IDs necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I had to in the end recompile the kernel, also had to compile PCI-stub into the kernel table xhci_hcd out of the kernel

And do extra steps to get a nice small 43m Initrd.img instead of 450m